# Moving all pwd contents to pwd's parent directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, mv, files-folders

Another user asked about this and I'm looking for clarification because apparently I can't comment until I have 50 pts.

One of the given answers for moving everything(including hidden items) up a level was:

```
mv /path/subfolder/{.,}* /path/
```

what I want to know is, could one more simply write:

```
mv ~/{.,}* ../
```

???

Thanks

Comment: You could, but that would likely do something different, and possibly give you a permission denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two commands are equivalent *****:

```sh
mv /path/subfolder/{.,}* /path/
```

```sh
cd /path/subfolder
mv {.,}* ..
```

The two commands accomplish the exact same move operation.

** If `/path/subfolder` is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to another directory, and that directory is not a direct child of `/path`, then they're NOT equivalent; your files will move somewhere else.*

### Explanation of what `~` means

`~` expands out to the value of `$HOME` which is usually `/home/<my username>`.

Given your $HOME is `/home/myusername`, running `mv ~/{.,}* ../` expands out to:

```sh
mv /home/myusername/{.,}* ../
```

(Running this command will seriously screw up your home directory, so don't run either your shortened version or my expanded version.)

### What even is `..`?

Depending on what directory you run this from, the actual location of `..` will change.

- From `/home/myusername/downloads/foo`, `..` is `/home/myusername/downloads`
- From `/` the location of `..` is still `/`

Run `realpath ..` to determine the exact path of `..`.

Caveat: Sometimes using [symbolically-linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) directories, `..` can refer to either one up from `$PWD` or the parent directory of the real directory. It all depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

No. `~` is your home directory. You cannot replace an arbitrary path with `~`. If `$(pwd)` is already the directory whose contents you want to move, though, you can do `mv ./{.,}* ../`.